# SWIG pass stream from python to C++

Tags: c++, python, stream, iostream, swig

**C++**
I have some logger class in C++. This logger is heavily used in my library. The logger allows to set standart STL stream to use as output stream.

**Python**
Python library which uses "above SWIG wrapped C++ library" heavily uses python standard logging with StreamHandler. Something like:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("base_logger")

#create and set console handler
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.stream = sys.stdout
logger.addHandler(ch)
```

**How to pass a python stream to C++ library as STL stream using SWIG?**

So one could make C++ to use your python stream. Something like:

```
ch = logger.handlers[NEEDED_HANDLER]
Swig_wrapped_lib.set_stream(ch.stream)
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you need to implement a swig typemap (in) that converts the python stream object into an std::ostream.  However, I fear that this is highly non-trivial.

Comment: Yes. And that is, actually, the question.